# copy union cell to different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code

```
Sub try()

Sheet_a = "Aladin"
Sheet_b = "Elenco Sedi"

a = "22"

b = "11"

Sheets(Sheet_a).Select

Worksheets(Sheet_a).Activate


       Set RangeUnionCopy = Union(Cells(a, 2), Cells(a, 3), Cells(a, 4), Cells(a, 5), Cells(a, 6), Cells(a, 7), Cells(a, 11), Cells(a, 12))
       Set RangeUnionPaste = Union(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b, 2), Cells(b, 4), Cells(b, 5), Cells(b, 6), Cells(b, 7), Cells(b, 11), Cells(b, 12))
       RangeUnionCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheet_b).Range(RangeUnionPaste.Address)

End Sub
```

don't work.. the problem it's in row RangeUnionCopy.Copy Destination:=Sheets(Sheet_b).Range(RangeUnionPaste.Address)
why ??

please help me to resolve this script

Comment: You cannot copy in that way **a discontinuous range**. You have to do it in steps of continuous ranges. Then `cells("22", 2)` has no meaning for VBA. It should be  `cells(22, 2)`. The row number must be numeric. If you do not need format copying, you can try: `Range("A11:B11").value = Range("B22:C22").value` and so on, for each continuous range.

Comment: For non-contiguous ranges, you can loop and `.value=.value` for each, though Fane hit the two overarching points that you're using a `string` instead of a `number` and you cannot paste into a non-contiguous destination (though you can copy from a non-contiguous range, `union()`, and paste into a contiguous, available range)